# Clicking on the button handler doesnt effect immediately

Tags: reactjs

Clicking on the button handler named handleDelivered immediately doesnt effect updatedQuantity.
For example - by default quantity = 10 which is initial value of updatedQuantity,
after clicking handleDelivered  it should decrease value by 1 and should print on the console "updatedQuantity after delivered 9" but its showing

****updatedQuantity after delivered 10**
**updatedQuantity before delivered 9****

**Code :**

```
const { name, artist, img, description, price, quantity, supplier } = album;

    const [updatedQuantity, setupdatedQuantity] = useState(quantity);
    useEffect(() => {
        setupdatedQuantity(quantity)
    }, [quantity])
    console.log("updatedQuantity before delivered", updatedQuantity);


    const handleDelivered = () => {
        if (updatedQuantity > 0) {
            setupdatedQuantity(updatedQuantity - 1);
            console.log("updatedQuantity after delivered", updatedQuantity);
    }
```

Comment: In React state update doesn't happen immediately. You have to wait until the component gets rendered.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your `handleDelivered`, method updating the state of `updatedQuantity` will only update it in the next rerender. This is usually fast enough if you need it somewhere else in the code. However if you need it immediately in `handleDelivered` you should use the value you've calculated.

```
    const handleDelivered = () => {
        if (updatedQuantity > 0) {
            const newQuantity = updatedQuantity - 1
            setupdatedQuantity(newQuantity);
            console.log("updatedQuantity after delivered", newQuantity);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use the previous value (`prev`) value in the set state.

```js
    const { name, artist, img, description, price, quantity, supplier } = album;

    const [updatedQuantity, setupdatedQuantity] = useState(quantity);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("updatedQuantity after delivered", quantity);
    }, [quantity])

    const handleDelivered = () => {
        if (updatedQuantity > 0) {
            setupdatedQuantity(prev => prev - 1);
        }
    // ...
    }
```

The reason I suggest this is because having the `setupdatedQuantity(prev => prev - 1);` will grab the current value on `updatedQuantity` (say 10), and then set the state to be a new value (9).

The `useEffect` will catch this 10 -> 9 change of `updatedQuantity` as it is in the deps array, and `console.log` it out to you.

**Here's the [example from the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)**

Comment: this is not going to fix the problem

Comment: https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/ <=== Monzur this is good to have in your tool-set. 
@rymanso - why it won't fix the problem?

Comment: because the issue is that state updates only register after one rerender. regardless of which initial value you use to update the state

Comment: useEffect will do the job (if we need to debug it).

Comment: `setState` will trigger a rerender just as `useEffect` would. but neither would trigger that rerender before the console.log runs

Comment: well yes, but that `console.log` is surely in the wrong place

Comment: i agree with that, maybe we are interpreting what OP wants to achieve in different ways. If you truly wanted to just console.log, then your solution works. But if you want to carry out some operation inside `handleDelivered`, using the calculated value may be preferable to triggering an extra useEffect

Comment: `useEffect` won't trigger re-render :) This will happen only (and only) if useReducer, setter given by useState are called or props of component has changed.

Answer (score 1):

use the callback function in the setState to get the updated value

```
 setupdatedQuantity(newQuantity, () => {
   console.log("updatedQuantity after delivered", updatedQuantity);
 });
```